# Error in a dependency / Syntax error in bower.json

Tags: visual-studio, npm, bower, asp.net-core

I created a new ASP.NET V5 web project, and added a NPM configuration (`package.json`) file:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "ASP.NET",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "bower": "1.4.1"
    }
}
```

Then I added a bower.json file:

```
{
    "name": "ASP.NET",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "*"
    }
}
```

I get the following error showing up:

[image]

---

#### Edit

This happens when I create an empty ASP.NET v5 project. When I create an MVC project, it works fine. I've managed to get the empty project to work when I add in all the client-side related items from the MVC project (e.g. gulpfile.js) so it must have been missing something it needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to uninstall the `bower` component from inside the `NPM` folder.

I had installed it earlier, then removed it from the `package.json` file, but it was still in the `NPM` folder. Once removed, it worked fine.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem and in my case the solution was:

1. Go to **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Project and Solutions** -> **External Web Tools**
2. Uncheck:

   - `.\node_modules\.bin`
   - `$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External`
   - `$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External\git`

Works fine under Visual Studio 2015 Community, however please bear in mind that I do have separately installed and configured both **nodejs** and **git** and I don't use any of VS built-in tools.

**UPDATE**

In Visual Studio 2017 Community the path is:

**Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Web Package Management -> External Web Tools**

Answer (score 4):

Something I did and it worked perfectly was:

1. Copy all the content (dependencies) of my .bower.json to a notepad (temporary backup)
2. Delete all dependencies from bower.json
3. Go to wwwroot/lib and delete manually all the libraries installed (good bye to all the folders there).
4. Copy the list of my dependencies from my temporary backup (notepad on point 1).
5. Save the file and wait.
6. Magically it works fine.

Comment: Note, you only need to delete the contents of `wwwroot/lib` if that's where you have bower putting your packages ... in [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ControlHowYourBowerPackagesAreInstalledWithAGulpfileInASPNET5.aspx) Scott Hanselman demonstrates a better way.  You really don't want e.g. all the bootstrap LESS files in `wwwroot` anyway ... and this has actually caused me issues when trying to publish.

Comment: this solution worked for me using .Net Core 1.0. I wanted to make note of that since things in Core have changed a bit from the Release Candidates

Comment: I had a syntax error in my bower.json (which was odd as I had never edited it)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but it was because I have disabled for some reason External Web Tools. For reactivation I had to go Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > External Web tools and check back all the options. By trial and error I found that the error disappear if at least $(PATH) is checked. I restarted Visual Studio.

[image: External Web Tools]

Comment: Excellent! Worked great for me, Visual Studio 2015, asp.net core 1.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and building upon Bartosz Lenar and marianc's answers, I can explain what was happening for me.

My dev environment is VS2015 Update 3. I have manually installed Node v7 onto my machine.

Starting with a fresh .NET Core template I proceeded to open the command prompt, and installed node, and grabbed a few packages, namely:

- gulp
- gulp-concat
- gulp-rename
- gulp-uglify
- gulp-sass

My I then proceeded to set up my JS minification using concat, rename and ugligy in my gulpfile.

Everything worked absolutely fine up until this point.

As soon as I referenced gulp-sass as a dependency, things started to go slightly wrong. This is where the bundled Node vs the Node I used from the command line started to conflict. The error was as follows (in VS Output window for 'Task Runner Explorer'):

> Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 32-bit with Node.js 5.x

This was solved by navigating to Options>Projects and Solutions>External Web Tools and adding my Node 7 install location in, at the top. (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/03/19/customize-external-web-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/)

This solved that issue entirely, Gulp was working.

Sadly I then got the same issue as Sean; my Bower dependency was throwing a syntax error.

This, as it turns out, is again due to conflicting versions. To start with I de-referenced everything in the Options dialog, apart from $PATH and my Node path. this fixed it; however I realised that actually, if I just put my $PATH to the top, VS would use the same version I reference from the command line.

[Options Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAAGO.png)

This solved it for me; and hopefully gives some explanation as to what's actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but for me I had to use `npm install -g bower` and add the path to the environment variables and It worked.

Comment: I had to do the same thing after installing Visual Studio 2017 on the same dev laptop with VS 2015. Mine is a older .NET Core 1.1 app I was editing and it lost the bower somehow after installing Angular etc on a newer 2017 VS project.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For this I suggest, first you have to check whether you have installed bower or not. for this you need to Open Command prompt with Administrative rights,
type bower.[image: Check Bower exists or not]

If Not exists then you have to install it by giving command [image: Install Bower]

Type Command **npm** at Command Prompt, you will have details of path at the end. Add this location to Visual Studio.
For this you need to follow this steps **Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > External Web tools**

[image: Add External Tools]

Restart Visual Studio and that's done. Hope So it Helps

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because of a syntax error in bower.json.
I had to right click the bower folder in VS and select "Open bower.json".
In the file there was a dependency without a colon and version string.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as both his posted code snippets are valid. You can add this as a comment though or ask for more details in a comment. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer